# speech recognition and audio recorder does not work at same time in some devices

Tags: android, kotlin, audio, speech-recognition, audio-recording

I am trying to record audio and speech to text at same time, however its not working in all Android devices.
Audio recorder work perfect in but speech recognition give error(ERROR CODE 2 and 5) in some devices.

Below is my code :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

   private fun recordingStart() {

    startRecordingAudio(activity)
    recognizerIntent =
        Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH) recognizerIntent !!. putExtra (RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, "en")
    recognizerIntent!!.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, activity?.packageName)
    recognizerIntent!!.putExtra(
        RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
        RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH
    )
    recognizerIntent!!.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, activity?.packageName)
    recognizerIntent!!.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 3)
    speech!!.startListening(recognizerIntent)
}

private fun recordingStop() {
    speech!!.stopListening()
    stopRecordingAudio(activity)
}


private var mRecorder: MediaRecorder? = null

fun startRecordingAudio(ctx: Context?) {

    mRecorder = MediaRecorder()
    mRecorder?.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
    mRecorder?.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)
    mFileName = ctx?.let {
        getStorageDirectory(it, "demo/audio")?.absolutePath
    } + "/" + Date().time + ".mp3"
    mRecorder?.setOutputFile(mFileName)
    mRecorder?.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC)
    mRecorder?.prepare()
    mRecorder?.start()

}

fun stopRecordingAudio(ctx: Context): Uri? {
    mRecorder?.stop()
    mRecorder?.reset()
    mRecorder?.release()
    return saveAudio(ctx)
}
```